# parse unique string based on a certain line

Tags: text-processing, grep, sort

I have a dhcpd.leases file with the following:

```
lease 172.231.100.152 {
starts 2 2017/11/14 14:50:41;
ends 2 2017/11/14 15:20:41; 
tstp 2 2017/11/21 15:05:41;
cltt 2 2017/11/14 14:50:41;
binding state active;
next binding state expired;

lease 172.231.100.152 {
starts 2 2017/11/14 14:50:41;
ends 2 2017/11/14 15:20:41; 
tstp 2 2017/11/21 15:05:41;
cltt 2 2017/11/14 14:50:41;
binding state active;
next binding state expired;

lease 172.231.100.152 {
starts 2 2017/11/14 14:50:41;
ends 2 2017/11/14 15:20:41; 
tstp 2 2017/11/21 15:05:41;
cltt 2 2017/11/14 14:50:41;
binding state free;
next binding state expired;

lease 172.231.100.151 {
starts 2 2017/11/14 14:50:41;
ends 2 2017/11/14 15:20:41; 
tstp 2 2017/11/21 15:05:41;
cltt 2 2017/11/14 14:50:41;
binding state active;
next binding state expired;

lease 172.231.100.152 {
starts 2 2017/11/14 14:50:41;
ends 2 2017/11/14 15:20:41; 
tstp 2 2017/11/21 15:05:41;
cltt 2 2017/11/14 14:50:41;
binding state free;
next binding state expired;
```

As you may know in this file some leases are recorded multiple times. I need a solution to only grep out a unique IP addresses RANGE using the 172.231.100 BUT only the ones that have a binding state of active. I am aware there are scripts out there that do this for you with DHCP but ours is not working atm and a command line solution for this would be great. Note the "binding state " line will always be the 6th line from the "lease" line.

Comment: *unique IP addresses* - your input contains only one IP address, extend your input to make it testable

Comment: Done. Just to clarify I just need all the IP's from a specific range, not just "unique IP addresses". Sorry for the confusion on that.

Comment: should we grep outputting 7-lined blocks?

Comment: 6 would do so we can leave off the last line

Comment: I'm not concerned with "next binding state"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**awk** solution:

```
awk '/^lease/ && !($2 in ips){ f=1; ips[$2]=$0; n=NR+5 }
     f && NR <= n{ 
         a[++c]=$0; 
         if (NR == n) { 
             if ($NF == "active;") { 
                 for (i=1; i<7; i++) print a[i]; print "" 
             } 
             c=0 
         } 
     }' dhcpd.leases
```

The output:

```
lease 172.231.100.152 {
starts 2 2017/11/14 14:50:41;
ends 2 2017/11/14 15:20:41; 
tstp 2 2017/11/21 15:05:41;
cltt 2 2017/11/14 14:50:41;
binding state active;

lease 172.231.100.151 {
starts 2 2017/11/14 14:50:41;
ends 2 2017/11/14 15:20:41; 
tstp 2 2017/11/21 15:05:41;
cltt 2 2017/11/14 14:50:41;
binding state active;
```

Comment: Tested on mine. Works like a charm thanks Roman!

Comment: @user53029, you're welcome